# React native build error: Attempt to invoke virtual method'boolean com.facebook.react.uimanager.FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrappper()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

My previous builds work fine, but now I'm getting this error when I try to take a build. I don't know how to resolve this error.

If anyone faces the same issue please help me out.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method'boolean com.facebook.react.uimanager.FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrappper()' on a null object reference
```

[image]

Answer (score 105):

I was able to narrow down what was causing the error for me by using `adb logcat` and tracing the app.

The issue stemmed from both `<Input>` (from `react-native-elements`) and `<TextInput>` (from `react-native`).  Both would cause the error, and the app would run without error if I commented out any Input/TextInput elements in the Componenets.

I wasn't quite able to get it to work with @kangear 's response, but it was close.  After a lot of digging and testing, I was able to get the app to work properly with the following line of code in `android\app\build.gradle`, in `dependencies` section:

```
implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
    version {
        strictly '1.3.1'
    }
}
```

I tried just using `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'`, but that wouldn't work either.

Hope this is able to save someone some time, as it took me quite a long time to figure it out!

Comment: For anyone getting here after adding stripe to react native, it's `implementation(project(':stripe_stripe-react-native')) { exclude module: 'appcompat' }` as well as the above.

Comment: @JordanRobinson comment works for me, using the last version of react native stripe, upgrading kotlinVersion to 1.6.0. Thanks, you save me hours of debugging.

Comment: but I add following code lines and it works 

`implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1"

 implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.3.1"`

Comment: Works well with react native version 0.66.1

Answer (score 15):

I had same issue for this.
do not use `+`

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0-alpha01"
```

or

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:+"
```

Correct way:(lower than `1.4`)

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
```

see here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31572

## update

```
./gradlew -q app:dependencies > 1.txt
```

maybe you can see this:

```
| +--- com.github.AnJiaoDe:TabLayoutNiubility:V1.1.6 | | \--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:+ -> 1.4.0-alpha01 (*)
```

3rd lib content a `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:+`

so you must be:

```
implementation ('com.github.AnJiaoDe:TabLayoutNiubility:V1.1.6') {
exclude group: 'androidx.appcompat', module: 'appcompat'
}
```

Comment: Works for me!!! In my case module was within a project so: 
```implementation(project(':project-name')) {
exclude module: 'appcompat'
}
```
Thanks!

Comment: where did you add this implementation(project(':project-name')) { exclude module: 'appcompat' }

Answer (score 8):

#### android/app/build.gradle

paste the following code in dependencies section

```
implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
        version {
            strictly '1.3.1'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can update `react-native` version to `0.68.2`.

This worked for me.

Verify Gradle version: `7.0.2`

Comment: I just needed to change react-native version to this one and worked!

Answer (score -1):

I Solve This Error Simple way.
**No.1)** create new expo project **expo init {yourProjectName}**
**No.2)** Your previous project **copy** all your create folder and files and **copy** you will install dependencies command.
**No.3)** You New Project Paste all folder and files and install all previous dependencies.
Now you run Your Project **npm start or yarn start**.
I hope your problem solve.

Answer (score -2):

**Update:** This solution is for those who can't afford to use Appcompat 1.3.1.

Other solutions were not viable for me. Downgrading to appcompat to 1.3.1 is not a good solution. And upgrading to 0.68.2 is also quite an effort.

I instead

- forked react-native version that I was on.
- made the changes mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/e21f8ec34984551f87a306672160cc88e67e4793)
- Re-built the ReactAndroid-release.aar by following [this](https://reactnative.dev/contributing/how-to-build-from-source)
- place ReactAndroid-release.aar in android/app/libs

And now you can use Appcompat 1.4.x on any React native version.
Tried on 0.64.3.

Comment: Forking an entire library, is a bad idea. You will have to manually update it every time, won't you?

Comment: @Keselme Agreed but old version of react native are not well supported by Facebook and in case we are on a version like 0.64.x, it's not like we are going to get any updates. And building react native from source is well documented by Facebook. Fixing this seems like the best way. If someday we move to latest React native version, we can point back to their repo.

Comment: @Keselme Just to clarify, you can continue using react native repo. Forked repo was only used to generate patched ReactAndroid-release.aar that is placed in android/app/libs.