# React Native Android production build crashes on physical device

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'd like to test an android production build of a React-Native (v0.67.4, Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.1.2, Gradle Version 7.2 ) app on a device but it crashes immediately.

It works fine on dev mode (launched with `npm run android:dev`)

According to RN’s doc, the command `cd android && ./gradlew bundleProductionRelease` successfully generates the `android/app/build/outputs/bundle/productionRelease/app-production-release.aab` file.

Then I try `npx react-native run-android --variant=productionRelease` to test the bundle on a physical device. As seen in attached `build.gradle`, signing seems to be correctly set.
Despite a bunch of warnings on the template :

> Gradle detected a problem with the following location:
> '*/path/to/our/app*'. Reason: Task
> ':app:bundleProductionReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task
> ':react-native-keychain:*variousTasksNames*' without declaring an
> explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results
> being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed

build ends successfully, app is installed on the device and launched, but crashes immediately.

Logs in Android studio says :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're
> either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your
> bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

which led me to this kind of solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399952/16121576, but unfortunately, as one of comments says, `cd android && ./gradlew bundleProductionRelease`  fails thereafter (`Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProductionReleaseResources' in my case`) so I revert back.

`package.json` :

```js
{
  "name": "equivintage_app",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "android:dev": "ENVFILE=.env.android.dev react-native run-android --variant=developmentdebug",
    "android:dev-release": "react-native run-android --variant=developmentrelease",
    "android:prod": "ENVFILE=.env.prod react-native run-android --variant=productiondebug",
    "android:prod-release": "react-native run-android --variant=productionrelease",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "ios:dev": "react-native run-ios --scheme \"equivintage_app_dev\"",
    "ios:prod": "react-native run-ios --scheme \"equivintage_app_prod\"",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^5.3.0",
    "@react-aria/ssr": "^3.1.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.7.0",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^1.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "axios-auth-refresh": "^3.2.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "native-base": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.4",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.23",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^2.3.10",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

`build.gradle` :

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// --- Added for react-native-config .env handler https://www.bigbinary.com/learn-react-native/handling-environment-specific-configurations-in-react-native
apply from: project(":react-native-config").projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
  productiondebug: ".env.prod",
  productionrelease: ".env.prod",
  developmentdebug: ".env.android.dev",
  developmentrelease: ".env.android.dev",
];
// ---

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for in debug.
 */
def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.equivintage"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 307
        versionName "3.1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            // --- Added for react-native-config .env handler https://www.bigbinary.com/learn-react-native/handling-environment-specific-configurations-in-react-native
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
            // ---
            if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"

        }
    }

    // --- Added for react-native-config .env handler https://www.bigbinary.com/learn-react-native/handling-environment-specific-configurations-in-react-native
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
      development {
      }
      production {
      }
    }
    // ---

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

//  To resolve "Attempt to invoke virtual method'boolean com.facebook.react.uimanager.FabricViewStateManager.hasStateWrappper()" error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683149/react-native-build-error-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-methodboolean-com-facebook)
    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1") {
    version {
        strictly '1.3.1'
    }
}
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Is there another lead I could follow ? Any help would be much appreciated.